# Make plugin permission appear on permission list, without defining control panel section

Tags: plugin-development

How can i make plugin permission appear on permissions list, without setting `public $hasCpSection = true;` in main plugin class?

For now i set this variable to `true` and then removed section link like this:

```
    public function getCpNavItem()
    {
        return null;
    }
```

But i am wondering if there is any other way.

Answer (score 3):

You can add permissions using the event `EVENT_REGISTER_PERMISSIONS`:

#### Craft 4

```php
use craft\events\RegisterUserPermissionsEvent;
use craft\services\UserPermissions;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(
    UserPermissions::class,
    UserPermissions::EVENT_REGISTER_PERMISSIONS,
    function(RegisterUserPermissionsEvent $event) {
        $event->permissions[] = [
            'heading' => 'Permission Group Name',
            'permissions' => [
                'permissionName' => [
                    'label' => 'Permission Label',
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
);
```

#### Craft 3

```php
use craft\events\RegisterUserPermissionsEvent;
use craft\services\UserPermissions;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(
    UserPermissions::class,
    UserPermissions::EVENT_REGISTER_PERMISSIONS,
    function(RegisterUserPermissionsEvent $event) {
        $event->permissions['Permission Group Name'] = [
            'permissionName' => [
                'label' => 'Permission Label',
            ],
        ];
    }
);
```

See the [documentation on user permissions](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/user-permissions.html) for details. The example is taken straight from the documentation. In the code above, `Permission Group Name` should be the name of your plugin. `permissionName` is the machine name you can use in your code to check for the permission and `Permission Label` is the human-readable label displayed in the CP.

See [requiring permissions](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/user-permissions.html#requiring-permissions) and [checking permissions](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/user-permissions.html#checking-permissions) for details on using permissions in Twig, custom controllers and other code.

Comment: Craft 4 require a new syntax: https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/user-permissions.html

Comment: @RomainPoirier Thanks for the reminder, I've updated my answer, added the code example for Craft 4 and changed the links to point to the current docs.